# How can I overlay the status/notification bar over my activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

I have an app where one activity doesn't need an Action bar. I am supporting ICS and above. I can't seem to figure out a way to overlay the notification bar over my activity.

This is what I have going:

```
 <!--this will hide the action bar-->
    <style name="AppFullScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
```

And I am just applying this theme to the activity I want like so:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.WalkthroughActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppFullScreenTheme"
       />
```

It shows a black background under the status bar. I want it to be overlaying my activity because I have a background on the activity. How would I do that?

Comment: And you are extending from Activity and not AppCompactActivity right?

Comment: @woooh77 I am extending from a BaseActivity that is extending from AppCompatActivity